# Best practice for dotNET project with mssql database replication

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nosql, replication

I'm working on a web project using C#, entity framework 4, mssql.
while the data grows bigger (not very big, but hard for single server), 
we decided to change something in the data access layer to enhance the throughput and performance.

Because change the database to a nosql one is costly for refactor, 
we'd plan use database replication, which i'v never used it before.

- Should we use more than one "connection strings", which used explicitly by the programmers according to "read" or "write" ops?
- Will reading the slaves cause "dirty" read?
- Any other best practices to deal this problem with minimized refactor cost?

we are not restricted to mssql server.

ps:we don't have many tables, but there are some **social** data that would be big enough and hard to separate table/database.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need NoSQL, you need to get rid of "The Database Syndrome" :)

It means that instead of One Big Database you can have a set of smaller ones. I am pretty much sure that your system has a number of different concerns. For example: billing, shipping, etc.

Why not separate these concerns into different databases? So your "billing" subsystem will have its own database, "shipping" - another, whatever you have as much as you have.

It gets now much easier to scale: you can simply put them on a separate server each if you need, or give an important one a dedicated hardware and have the rest together, etc.

It will also be much easier to manage: you can separately change things in one context without impacting others.

This is what is a "best practice" and what is a part of SOA style ;)

Another (less preferable in my eyes) is what is called "horizontal sharding". Say, your system operates with "projects" and you can simply put each "project" (and all its data) into separate databases.
It would also work, but does't fit everything and has its own tricks.

Comment: @alexey-raga thanks for your advice! we do separate some data by business-domains, but there are still something big. we have some social data, such as "who followed who", "who and who are in a same group"(groups is UGC), these data could not be easily separated and hard to tell hot from cold, but queries is much more than writes, that's why i consider **replication**. about SOA, while we distributed data, shall we need some kinds of _sync-frameworks_ in the database level? such as _users_ and _organizes_, which should be used in most _business-domains_.

Comment: Why not separate concerns feather then?
If you query much more than write, why using normalized data for queries, it will always be hard! Shy not write your data into SQL and then asynchronously and continuously transform it into something read-friendly? Basically you it once instead of doing it within every query. It is called "projecting data". For example, project "who followed who" into graph db and query from there.

Comment: You will only need one additional step: once new data is written you "translate" it into read-friendly store and update read models. The "source of truth" is still your SQL data and you should be able to rebuild your read models from scratch from SQL by projecting this data again. But when you do it continuously it is much smaller scope (as oppose to SQL query) so it is much faster. Then your clients will be able to read from a read-friendly and fast model, and forget about slow complicated queries nightmare :)